# Split string with last 2 whitespaces

Tags: python, python-3.x

for splitting words

```
value = "HELLO HOW ARE YOU WHAT ARE YOU DOING"
result = value.split(" ",2)

>> output will be:['HELLO','HOW', 'ARE YOU WHAT ARE YOU DOING']
```

But what if I want such result

```
output: ['HELLO HOW ARE YOU WHAT ARE' ,'YOU' ,'DOING']
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [rsplit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit)

```
value = "HELLO HOW ARE YOU WHAT ARE YOU DOING"
result = value.rsplit(" ", 2)
print(result) # ['HELLO HOW ARE YOU WHAT ARE', 'YOU', 'DOING']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `rsplit` instead of `split`.

```
In[7]: s.rsplit(" ", 2)
Out[7]: ['HELLO HOW ARE YOU WHAT ARE', 'YOU', 'DOING']
```

Comment: Hi, nice answer, nut how is this different than @Guy's answer?

Comment: based on the timing, I think that the two answered almost at the same time. @Guy was simply faster

Comment: @Stefan don't you think this happens quite often on SO that multiple people answer with same/similar response at the same time.